# How to make part title and part number next to each other

Tags: titlesec, parts

Using `\documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{report}`

by default when adding new chapter/part, what I get is:

`PART 1`

`MyPARTName`

I would like to get something like:

`1. MyPARTName`

I managed to remove PART text, but I am unable to remove newline there and for this I am using titlesec package. My code is following:

How can I remove ending newline after part number.

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thepart.}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\part} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\title{Test title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\part{Intro}
 asdf
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* minimum working example (MWE), including the `\documentclass`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `block` style of `titlesec` and redefine `\thepart`:

```
\documentclass[tiitlepage, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[block]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thepart.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\part} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

 \part{Introduction}
 \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]